# Getting a response header from an NSMutableURLRequest

Tags: cocoa, macos

Hi all im having a bunch of crappy looking code here (dont get me on that). This code is posting a new entry on pastebin.com. Once you posted something on pastebin it will forward you to a new url address in php it uses header('Location:....');.

What i want to know is how to get the forwarded url from this NSMutableURLRequest..

PS: Debug output ==

2009-08-20 17:51:13.025 PasteBin[28620:a0f] Error: (null)
2009-08-20 17:51:13.026 PasteBin[28620:a0f] Response: {
    Connection = "Keep-Alive";
    "Content-Type" = "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1";
    Date = "Thu, 20 Aug 2009 15:51:12 GMT";
    "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=15, max=100";
    Server = "Apache/1.3.33 (Debian GNU/Linux) mod_python/2.7.10 Python/2.3.4 PHP/4.3.10-22 mod_perl/1.29";
    "Transfer-Encoding" = Identity;
    "X-Powered-By" = "PHP/4.3.10-22";
}

I hope some one can help me out please.

Answer (score 2):

You don't get anything from the request; the request is what you send to the server. You would get the information you're looking for from the response.

Don't forget to look in `NSHTTPURLResponse` and not just its more-general superclass.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer

its:

[response URL];